# Xcode: XML link with quotations parsing issue

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, xml-parsing, quotes

I am trying to parse XML, but the XML code has quotations which is making a problem and it won't run. Is there way to call this xml `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392">` as shown in the code?

Thank in advance.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@" table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392" "] ) {

        [[self titleArray] addObject:[self currentStringValueTitle]];


    }


    [self setCurrentStringValueTitle:nil];
```

I wanna read this source page

```
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392">
    <tr>
        <td width="392" class="hdlnType2">
        <div
            style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 1.12em; FLOAT: left; ">
            <!-- enable chat --> 


        I wanna print this text....

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]){

         NSString *border=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"border"];
         NSString *cellpadding=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"cellpadding"];
         NSString *cellspacing=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"cellspacing"];
         NSString *width=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"width"];

     }


     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"div"]){

         //fetch values here like did for table tag from attributedDict

     }
} 


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
if(!currentElementValue) 
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
//NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"div"]) {
            NSLog(currentElementValue,nil);
        }
        [currentElementValue release];
        currentElementValue = nil;
 }
```

The parameters of any tag will be parsed and saved in to attributedDict pararameter of didStartElement method

Comment: Thank you, Normally I wanna read the value that inside the table so should I write "body" in the didStartElement?
    `<body> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392"> <tr> <td width="392" class="hdlnType2"> <div style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 1.12em; FLOAT: left; "> <!-- enable chat --> Talebiniz için herhangi bir sonuç bulunamadı Lütfen yeniden deneyiniz</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> </tr> </table>`

Comment: The values that inside the <table> can be read in the didEndElement method normally but if you want read tag parameters it can be done in didStartElement's attributedDict for that I guess you need not to append anyother tag as a parent of that perticular tag.

Comment: Thank you again, I want to read the value inside the table, I have added the page source code which I hope could explain what I want.

Comment: At Kuldeep: I would like to ask question which confuses me, shouldn't I write the body tag in the DidStartElement and the table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392" tag in the didEndElement?

Comment: I wanna print the text inside the table tag so could you please help me? Thanks

Comment: No the tag parameters can be received only in didStartElement's attributedDict parameter as didEndElement doesn't have any attributedDict as a parameter.

Comment: Actually what you finally want to do let me know I will set the code according that you just need to copy&paste.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I couldn't explain well... I don't want to print the parameters I just want to print the text which is in black color as in the web code. For example '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="392">' the text
    <tr>
        <td width="392" class="hdlnType2">
        <div
            style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 1.12em; FLOAT: left; ">
            <!-- enable chat -->'

Comment: Ok so the code I have prepared will print that line "I wanna print this text" by the piece of code that contains if([elementName isEqualToString:@"div"]) in didEndElement. Let me know if any confusions.

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep I get  the idea.